# List box validation in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, multi-select, requiredfieldvalidator

Hi how to set required feild validator for multi select list box in asp.net?

I tried in default way something like

initial value = "0" for required feild validator. But it is not working for me.

Any example?

Answer (score 1):

U can use the custom validation for that..

```
 protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (ListBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

may be this will help you

Answer (score 1):

A small correction to your code is in order since it always returns false:

```
  protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
       args.IsValid = (ListBox1.Items.Count > 0);
    }
```